# Complexity \ Reference request for variant of max flow problem

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, network-flow

In the standard max **cost** flow problem with arc capacities, the cost of using an arc is proportional to the flow through the arc. For example, if $f_{uv}$ is the flow through the arc $(u,v)$, then the cost of using this arc is given by $\mathbf{c}_{uv} f_{uv}$, where $\mathbf{c}_{uv}$ is some predefined real number. So the objective we are interested in maximizing is $\underset{(u, v) \in E}{\sum} \mathbf{c}_{uv} f_{uv}$, where $E$ is the edges in the graph. You may assume that graph contains a source and a sink node, and all flows emanate from the source and drain into the sink node.

Consider the variant in which the cost associated with using the arc $(u,v)$ is instead given by:
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{c}_{uv} f_{uv} + \mathbf{b}_{uv}, \text{ if } f_{uv} > 0,\\
0, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
where $\mathbf{b}_{uv}$ is some predefined positive number.

1. Does the variant of the max flow problem admit a polynomial-time solution?
2. If not, are there any references that you can point me to?

P.S. I know that the variant I stated can be posed easily as a MILP, however, I am interested in learning about the structural results and complexity of this problem.

Comment: Is your objective to maximize the sum of the weighted flows, or are you looking for the weighted minimum-cost solution given that the unweighted flow is equal to the maximum (a min-cost max-flow problem)?

Comment: @KevinDalmeijer - The OP should have read max cost flow. So yes, I am interested in maximizing the sum of weighted flows, where the weights for the edges are provided in the $\mathbf{c}$ vector.

Comment: You want to *maximize* cost?  Are there any demand constraints on the nodes?  Do you have a source node and a sink node?

Comment: @RobPratt - Just the simplest case where we have a source and a sink node, and we want to find the flow from source to sink that costs the most. I will clarify this in the OP as well.

Comment: In this case, the standard form would be to multiply all weights by -1 and state it as an equivalent min-cost flow problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would assume, that there doesn't even exist an optimal solution.

You want to have $\epsilon$-flow across every edge to collect all the cost $b_{uv}$. On the other hand you want to maximize the flow across the edges with the highest cost $c_{uv}$. This leads to pressure to have $\epsilon$ as small as possible, while still $\epsilon > 0$. Such an $\epsilon$ cannot exist.

Comment: I agree. The goal is to maximize an objective function that is not upper semi-continuous, which is going to lead to problems except in trivial cases.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a great point. I think a max may not exist, but a supremum will exist though. Is there an efficient procedure to compute the sup value?